# Using bouncycastle library in my spring boot project but officially documented API can not be resolved when import

Tags: java, spring-boot, build.gradle, bouncycastle

In my spring Boot project, I would like to use this [X509v3CertificateBuilder](https://www.bouncycastle.org/docs/pkixdocs1.5on/org/bouncycastle/cert/X509v3CertificateBuilder.html) class for creating self-signed certificate.

I have added the dependency in project's `build.gradle.kts` based on the [maven repo](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.bouncycastle/bcprov-jdk15on/1.70):

```
dependencies {
  ...
  implementation("org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15on:1.70")
}
```

When I write code in my project on IntelliJ IDE:

```
// X509v3CertificateBuilder can not be resolved
X509v3CertificateBuilder certBuilder = new X509v3CertificateBuilder(...)
```

The `X509v3CertificateBuilder` can not be resolved, auto-import can't find it.

I also tried explicitly import it:

```
// the 'cert' package can not be resolved
import org.bouncycastle.cert.X509v3CertificateBuilder
```

The `cert` package can not be resolved.

Where am I missing to use the library?

(If there are other ways to create self-signed X.509 certificate please also let me know. Thanks.)

Comment: `X509v3CertificateBuilder` isn't in the main jar, it's in `pkix`.

Comment: You need this one: https://central.sonatype.com/artifact/org.bouncycastle/bcpkix-jdk18on